# Getting an AppleScript property of an NSAppleEventDescriptor

Tags: cocoa, applescript, appleevents

I'm trying to use some Apple Events in my Cocoa project to get access to the Terminal application. I did not want to use embedded AppleScripts or any compiled scripts, so I started looking into the `NSAppleEventDescriptor`.

I have succeeded in creating a new window using the `do script` command, and I have succeeded to get the window from the return value. The only thing I want to do right now is get a property of that window.

I had now idea how to get such a property, so I started googling. Unfortunately, there aren't a lot of good examples how to use Apple Events, and I failed to find what I was looking for.

So I started digging deeper. And the first thing I did was looking for the code for the `get` command in the Terminal `.sdef` file. I failed to find it, so I did a `grep` on my `/System/` directory and I found `/System/Library/Frameworks/AppleScriptKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/AppleScriptKit.sdef`. I apparently found the core of the AppleScript syntax. That file did indeed have the `getd` four character code.

So now I know I have to use the `getd` event from the Core Suite. However, the argument to that get-command was an `objectSpecifier`. I have searched high and low for an example that uses `kAEGetData`. But I have failed to find any code from which I could learn anything.

So I am asking here: **how do I build such an `objectSpecifier` descriptor?**

This is what I've already got:

**Code to create and get the tab descriptor**

```
NSAppleEventDescriptor *createEvent;
NSAppleEventDescriptor *scriptParam;
AppleEvent aeReply;
OSErr err;

/* Make the do script event */
createEvent = [NSAppleEventDescriptor 
               appleEventWithEventClass:kAECoreSuite 
               eventID:kAEDoScript 
               targetDescriptor:_applicationDescriptor 
               returnID:kAutoGenerateReturnID 
               transactionID:kAnyTransactionID];
if(createEvent == nil) {
    NSLog(@"%s Failed to create a do script event",
          __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return nil;
}

/* Make script parameter */
scriptParam = [NSAppleEventDescriptor descriptorWithString:@"echo Hello World"];
if(scriptParam == nil) {
    NSLog(@"%s Failed to create the script parameter",
          __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return nil;
}

/* Set parameter */
[createEvent setParamDescriptor:scriptParam forKeyword:keyDirectObject];

/* Send event */
err = AESendMessage([createEvent aeDesc], &aeReply, 
                    kAEWaitReply | kAENeverInteract, kAEDefaultTimeout);
if(err != noErr) {
    NSLog(@"%s Failed to send the create command", 
          __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return nil;
}

/* Retrieve information */
{
    /* SEE BELOW TO SEE HOW I GET THE WINDOW DESCRIPTOR */
}
```

**Now I try and succeed in getting the window of that tab**

```
   // NSAppleEventDescriptor *ansr is set to the result of the code above

NSAppleEventDescriptor *mainObj;
NSAppleEventDescriptor *desiredClass;
NSAppleEventDescriptor *window;

mainObj = [ansr paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject];
if([mainObj descriptorType] != typeObjectSpecifier) {
    NSLog(@"%s Main object was not an object specifier",
          __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return nil;
}

desiredClass = [mainObj paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyAEDesiredClass];
if([desiredClass typeCodeValue] != kAETerminalTab) {
    NSLog(@"%s Main object's desired class was not a Terminal tab",
          __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return nil;
}

window = [mainObj paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyAEContainer];
if(window == nil) {
    NSLog(@"%s Couldn't get container of the tab",
          __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return nil;
}

desiredClass = [window paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyAEDesiredClass];
if([desiredClass typeCodeValue] != cWindow) {
    NSLog(@"%s The container of the tab was not a window",
          __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return nil;
}

return window;
```

**And now I fail in getting, let's say, the bounds property**

```
// _windowDescriptor is the result of the code above

NSAppleEventDescriptor *getEvent;
NSAppleEventDescriptor *prop;
AppleEvent aeReply;
NSAppleEventDescriptor *reply;
FourCharCode propName;
OSErr err;

propName = keyAEBounds;

/* Create get event */
getEvent = [NSAppleEventDescriptor
            appleEventWithEventClass:kAECoreSuite 
            eventID:kAEGetData 
            targetDescriptor:_windowDescriptor 
            returnID:kAutoGenerateReturnID 
            transactionID:kAnyTransactionID];
if(getEvent == nil) {
    NSLog(@"%s Failed to create a get event",
          __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return NSZeroRect;
}

/* Get property */
prop = [NSAppleEventDescriptor
        descriptorWithDescriptorType:typeProperty 
        bytes:&propName length:sizeof(propName)];
if(prop == nil) {
    NSLog(@"%s Failed to create the bounds property",
          __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return;
}

/* Set parameter */
[getEvent setParamDescriptor:prop forKeyword:keyDirectObject];

/* Exectue */
err = AESendMessage([getEvent aeDesc], &aeReply, 
                    kAEWaitReply | kAENeverInteract, kAEDefaultTimeout);
if(err != noErr) {
    NSLog(@"%s Failed to send the get message",
          __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    return;
}

reply = [[NSAppleEventDescriptor alloc] initWithAEDescNoCopy:&aeReply];
[reply autorelease];

NSLog(@"Bounds: %@", reply);
```

As explained, the above code works, just until the last block.
Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Rob Keniger I've succeeded in what I wanted.

Apparently I had to create a record descriptor, set my wanted properties and, then **coerce** it to a `typeObjectSpecifier`.

Also, I was wrong in setting the window descriptor as a the receiver of my Apple Event. You always have to address the application itself, and set the `from` (`keyAEContainer`) property of the direct object to the window you want.

Here is the working code, with a little bit of `NSLog`-statements:

```
- (NSRect)bounds {

    // ! ! !
    // _windowDescriptor is an instance variable which points to a valid
    // window NSAppleEventDescriptor
    // ! ! !

    NSAppleEventDescriptor *getEvent;
    NSAppleEventDescriptor *objSpec;
    NSAppleEventDescriptor *propEnum, *propType, *propSeld;
    AppleEvent aeReply;
    NSAppleEventDescriptor *reply;
    FourCharCode propName;
    OSErr err;

    propName = keyAEBounds;

    /* Create get event */
    getEvent = [NSAppleEventDescriptor
                appleEventWithEventClass:kAECoreSuite 
                eventID:kAEGetData 
                targetDescriptor:[[FTMTerminalApp sharedApp] AEDescriptor] 
                returnID:kAutoGenerateReturnID 
                transactionID:kAnyTransactionID];
    if(getEvent == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%s Failed to create a get event",
              __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
        return NSZeroRect;
    }

    /* Get property */
    /* create object specifier main ojcect */
    objSpec = [[[NSAppleEventDescriptor alloc] initRecordDescriptor] 
               autorelease];
    if(objSpec == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%s Failed to create the object specifier",
              __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
        return NSZeroRect;
    }
    NSLog(@"%s Created object specifier %@",
          __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, objSpec);

    /* create property enum, we want a property */
    propEnum = [NSAppleEventDescriptor
                descriptorWithEnumCode:formPropertyID];
    if(propEnum == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%s Failed to create the property enum",
              __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
        return NSZeroRect;
    }
    NSLog(@"%s Created property enum %@",
          __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, propEnum);
    [objSpec setDescriptor:propEnum forKeyword:keyAEKeyForm];

    /* create prop type */
    propType = [NSAppleEventDescriptor
                descriptorWithTypeCode:typeProperty];
    if(propType == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%s Failed to create the property type",
              __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
        return NSZeroRect;
    }
    NSLog(@"%s Created property type %@",
          __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, propType);
    [objSpec setDescriptor:propType forKeyword:keyAEDesiredClass];

    /* create property key data */
    propSeld = [NSAppleEventDescriptor
                descriptorWithTypeCode:keyAEBounds];
    if(propSeld == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%s Failed to create the bounds property type",
              __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
        return NSZeroRect;
    }
    NSLog(@"%s Created property key data %@",
          __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, propSeld);
    [objSpec setDescriptor:propSeld forKeyword:keyAEKeyData];

    /* Set destination */
    NSLog(@"%s Setting from key %@",
          __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, _windowDescriptor);
    [objSpec setDescriptor:_windowDescriptor forKeyword:keyAEContainer];

    /* Send message */
    objSpec = [objSpec coerceToDescriptorType:typeObjectSpecifier];
    NSLog(@"Coerced: %@", objSpec);
    [getEvent setParamDescriptor:objSpec forKeyword:keyDirectObject];
    err = AESendMessage([getEvent aeDesc], &aeReply, 
                        kAEWaitReply | kAENeverInteract, kAEDefaultTimeout);
    if(err != noErr) {
        NSLog(@"%s Failed to send the message (event = %@)",
              __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, getEvent);
        return NSZeroRect;
    }

    reply = [[NSAppleEventDescriptor alloc] initWithAEDescNoCopy:&aeReply];
    NSLog(@"BOUNDS = %@", reply);
    [reply autorelease];

    return NSZeroRect;
}
```

I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Apple Events are complicated to use. Unless you really want to spend the time working through the convoluted and generally nasty API, I recommend that you save yourself a lot of time and heartache by using Mike Ash's excellent [`AEVTBuilder`](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?AEVTBuilder) class.

It's a nice Cocoa wrapper for all the nasty Carbon Apple Event code.

Comment: Actually I'd really like to use the core of the Apple Event API.

Comment: That's great, I'm glad I was able to help a little.